# If , $a\in\mathbb N $ s.t. $(a+x)^{\frac{1}{3}}+(a-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}=3(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$Q.$ Solve for $x$ , If $(a,x)\in\mathbb N $ s.t. $$(a+x)^{\frac{1}{3}}+(a-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}=3(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$\Rightarrow$ My approach was to cube both the sides : First let , $\underbrace{3(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}_\Lambda$  So , by cubing both sides we get , $$\Lambda^3-\Lambda^2=2a$$

If $(a^2-x^2)$ is a whole cube then $3(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}\in\mathbb N$ now according to the above condition , i.e. $\Lambda^3-\Lambda^2=2a$

hence , $a\in\{2,9,24,50,.......\frac{n^2(n-1)}{2}\}$

I'm not able to proceed form here , Much thank you

Comment: Hint : write $a^2 - x^2 = (a-x)(a+x)$

Comment: I tried that too , but still nothing striked .

Comment: Is $0\in \Bbb N$, or not here?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I missed important point $x,a\in\mathbb N$ you are right.

Comment: @lonestudent I got that much of the solution , but ... it didn't worked . Can I use $p^3+q^3=(p+q)(p^2+q^2-pq)$ in the base eqation .

Comment: I think you'll have to solve the cubic...$p^3+q^3$ isn't really working out.

Comment: according to the base equation , we can say $(m-n)^2=mn$

Comment: @DietrichBurde I solved completely. But, it is possible that $m,n \not\in\mathbb Q$ but $x\in\mathbb N$. I could not escape from cubic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde We can not escape from cubic, **I think**

Comment: See , our goal is to make the equation simpler by removing the radicals so , lets assume that $(a^2-x^2) , (a+x)^{\frac{1}{3}} ,  (a+x)^{\frac{1}{3}}  $ is a whole cube . So now we can say that $a\in\{2,9,24,50,........,\frac{n^2(n-1)}{2}\}$

Comment: I agree with you ................. but thats the only problem . I did that by taking some assumptions

Comment: $$\Lambda^3-\Lambda^2=2a$$
I realized now. Did you do what I did?

Comment: Yep , thats what I was saying

Comment: I also said that , It is possible only on one condition if $a^2-x^2$ is a whole cube . @DietrichBurde

Comment: $\Lambda^3$ is an integer therefore $\Lambda^2$ is also an integer

Comment: by the way the problem was to Find $x$ with respect to $a$ or the value of $x$

Comment: $\Lambda $ is a rational number whose square is an integer

Comment: @sukrit I solved $a,x\in\mathbb Q$. More general.

Answer (score 3):

I claim that there are no solutions $x,a$ in positive integers.

To prove this, write $a+x=m$ and $a-x=n$ with $m\in \Bbb N$ and $n\in \Bbb Z$. Then the equation is
$$
m^{1/3}+n^{1/3}=3(mn)^{1/3}.
$$

We have $n<m$ because of $x>0$. Also $n=0$ gives $a=x$, which is a contradiction to the equation. The equation is equivalent to
$$
1+\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^{1/3}=3n^{1/3}.
$$
Suppose that $n$ is positive. Then the LHS is less than $2$, since $n<m$. So we obtain
$$
n^{1/3}<\frac{2}{3},
$$
which gives $n<1$. Since $n$ is positive, we have $n=0$, a contradiction. So $n$ is negative and the RHS of our original equation is negative, but the LHS is positive, because of
$$
(a+x)^{1/3}+(a-x)^{1/3}>0
$$
for $a,x$ positive integers.

Comment: Nice +1.  In fact your approach shows $1+((a-x)/(a+x))^{1/3} = 3(a-x)^{1/3}$ has no positive real solutions, as LHS < 2 and $RHS \ge 3$ (and obviously we have $a>x$).

Comment: @Macavity Thank you for your positive feedback! I was first tempted to view it as a Diophantine equation, but this is not intended, I suppose.

Comment: Same question as "lone student" about the downvoting - what is missing?

Comment: Very Interesting solution. Thinking it was a good (with solutions available) question, I focused only on the solution.  According to your solution, my solution seems garbage.  I hope at least it has rational roots.  The effort I put into my solution is wasted.

Comment: @lonestudent Thank you. I don't think it is wasted. A cubic equation is there, so one can study it.

Comment: You're correct , For this problem there is no solution of $x$ .